# Excel Macro Save As PDF Filename bug

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

Recently, I need to automate the file saving features inside Excel file and I manage to rig up basic macro that can save as PDF
Source: https://exceloffthegrid.com/vba-code-save-excel-file-as-pdf/ and https://www.contextures.com/excelvbapdf.html

Here is macro. The idea is user can save the current sheet in any folder locations that they want as PDF files.

The bugs looks like this. Supposedly , I have file named **A report template.xlsm** and I keyin the name that I wanted to save for example **Marketing - 15_5_2022.pdf** in a folder. 
Somehow, after saving, the file name will revert back to ***A report template*.pdf** instead of **Marketing - 15_5_2022.pdf**

Any ideas where do I go wrong in the codes?

```
Sub SaveAsPDF()

Dim PdfFilename As Variant

PdfFilename = Application.GetSaveAsFilename( _
    InitialFileName:="Dept - Due Date", _
    FileFilter:="PDF, *.pdf", _
    Title:="Save Report As PDF")

If PdfFilename <> False Then

    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=PdfFilenme, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=False, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=True

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Don't forget, filenames can't contain / or \ so you'll need to reformat your dates.

Comment: Good point, CLR. I edit the question for corrections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not setting the name of the file to be saved. Try:

```
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=PdfFilename, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=False, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=True
```

Regards,